# Can't apply migrations in Django SQLlite memory database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, testing

I'm writing some tests, and I want to be able to run django server with my test settings (that's why I'm using in-memory database).

It seems to be working, no errors reported when running. But migrations are not applied - I can't perform any action on the database, because model tables do not exist.

When I run `python manage.py migrate`, all my migrations get applied (I see these `Applying migrations... OK` messages), but it has no effect. When I run `python manage.py showmigrations`, none of the migrations are applied (I see `[ ] 0001_initial` etc., without the `X`).

When I go to django shell, I can't perform any action, because `table does not exist`. Any idea what might be the reason? It works fine with normal, postgres database.

My settings:

```py
DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
        'TEST_NAME': ':memory:',
    },
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': ''
    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Hey agamov, I think I didn't. If I remember correctly I found some information that it's not possible with the in memory database and switched to using Postgres db in a docker container, but it was so long ago that I'm not 100% sure, sorry about that :(